# saving data from form to table in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form, and I want to fill it, and then save some of the fields into an existing table called Order.
I'm trying to do this with this line of code:

> CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Order (OrderNumber)" & " VALUES (' " & Me.order & " ')"

I have also tried it like this

> CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Order (OrderNumber)" & " VALUES ( " & Me.order & " )"

but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I keep getting the following error:

> run-time error '3134': syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try printing the sql string you execute as a query? Maybe that this helps tracking the problem down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Order` is a reserved word.  If you must keep that as the table name, bracket it to avoid confusing the db engine.

```vb
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO [Order] (OrderNumber) VALUES ('" & Me.order & "')"
Debug.Print strInsert
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
```

If `OrderNumber` is numeric data type instead of text, discard those single quotes from the `INSERT` statement.

Store your statement in a string variable.  Then use `Debug.Print` to examine the completed statement you're asking the engine to execute.  You can view the `Debug.Print` output in the Immediate window.  Go there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>  Copy the statement and paste it into SQL View of a new Access query for troubleshooting.